# set button on action within method java

Tags: java, button, javafx, eventhandler

How could I **set the action of a button within the same method** I am creating the buttons?

My desired method would be something like this:

```
private void buttonsCreation() {
        //----------------creation of interactive buttons with text-----------------
        Button buttonForLoad = new Button("Load footage file");
        Button buttonForSave = new Button("Save footage file");
        Button buttonForSaveAs = new Button("Save as footage file");
        ButtonbuttonForRun = new Button("Run footage animation");
        Button buttonForTerminate = new Button("Stop footage animation");
        Button buttonForEditMenu = new Button("Edit current footage");
        //---------------setting the interaction of the buttons---------------------
        buttonForLoad.setOnAction(loadFootage());
        buttonForSave.setOnAction(saveFootage());
        buttonForSaveAs.setOnAction(saveAs());
        buttonForRun.setOnAction(runAnimation());
        buttonForTerminate.setOnAction(terminateAnimatino());
        buttonForEditMenu.setOnAction(editMenu());
    }
```

I would like the attributes of setOnAction to call those methods, but I receive this error. setOnAction in ButonBase can not be applied to void.

I am aware I can create a void handle with an ActionEvent as a parameter and make it work, but my desired function will be in one function, and if it is possible with **as least lines of code as possible**.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

To call void function in action handler, lambda expression is usefull. Like this:

```
buttonForLoad.setOnAction(e -> loadFootage());
buttonForSave.setOnAction(e -> saveFootage());
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe did you mean the action listener for example:

```
private void buttonsCreation() {
//------------creation of interactive buttons with text---------------

Button buttonForLoad = new Button("Load footage file");
buttonForLoad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // to do something
            }
        });

...
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged JavaFX, so presumably this is a JavaFX button, not an AWT button.