# Event handing issue in Controller in JavaFX and MVC (Not FXML)

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, event-handling, eventhandler

I am trying to handle event inside controller. How can i make "Create Profile" button work inside controller. Here are my classes:

main class

```
public class ApplicationLoader extends Application {

private OptionsModuleChooserRootPane view;

@Override
public void init() {
    StudentProfile model = new StudentProfile();
    view = new OptionsModuleChooserRootPane();
    new OptionsModuleChooserController(view, model);    
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setMinWidth(530); 
    stage.setMinHeight(550);
    stage.setTitle("Final Year Module Chooser Tool");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(view));
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Main View

```
public class OptionsModuleChooserRootPane extends BorderPane {

Menu fileMenu;
Menu helpMenu;
MenuBar menuBar;
TabPane tabPane;
List<Tab> tabs;

public CreateProfileTab profilePane;
public SelectModulesTab modulesPane;
public OverviewSelectionPane overviewPane;

public OptionsModuleChooserRootPane() {

    fileMenu = new Menu("File");
    helpMenu = new Menu("Help");
    menuBar = new MenuBar();
    tabPane = new TabPane();
    tabs = new ArrayList<>();

    //------------------ File menu ----------------------------
    fileMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Load Student Data"));
    fileMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Save Student Data"));
    fileMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Exit"));

    //----------------- Help menu -----------------------------
    helpMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("About"));

    //----------------- MenuBar containing all menus ---------
    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu,helpMenu);
    this.setTop(menuBar);       

    profilePane = new CreateProfileTab();
    modulesPane = new SelectModulesTab();
    overviewPane = new OverviewSelectionPane();

    //-------------------------------- Tabs -----------------------------------------------------
    tabs.add(addNewTab(tabPane, "Create Profile", profilePane, false)); 
    tabs.add(addNewTab(tabPane, "Select Modules", modulesPane, false));
    tabs.add(addNewTab(tabPane, "Overview Selection", overviewPane, false));

    this.setCenter(tabPane);
}

private Tab addNewTab(final TabPane tabPane, String newTabName, Pane newTabContent, boolean isCloseable) {
    Tab newTab = new Tab(newTabName);
    newTab.setContent(newTabContent);
    newTab.setClosable(isCloseable);

    tabPane.getTabs().add(newTab);
    return newTab;

}
}
```

I have created separate files for all three tabs. Here is the "Create Profile" tab class which has the button i am trying to handle event of.

```
public class CreateProfileTab extends GridPane {

private Label lSelectCousrse;
private ComboBox<Course> cboCourses;
private Label lPNumber;
private TextField tfPNumber;
private Label lFirstName;
private TextField tfFirstName;
private Label lSurname;
private TextField tfSurname;
private Label lEmail;
private TextField tfEmail;
private Label lDate;
private DatePicker datePicker;
private HBox hboxDate;
private Button btnCreateProfile;

private StudentProfile student = null;
private Name name;

public CreateProfileTab(){

    this.setMinSize(400, 200); 
    this.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10)); 
    this.setVgap(15); 
    this.setHgap(20);       
    this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); 

    lSelectCousrse = new Label("Select course:");
    cboCourses = new ComboBox<Course>();
    lPNumber = new Label("Input P number:");
    tfPNumber = new TextField();
    lFirstName = new Label("Input first name:");
    tfFirstName = new TextField();
    lSurname = new Label("Input surname");
    tfSurname = new TextField();
    lEmail = new Label("Input email:");
    tfEmail = new TextField();
    lDate = new Label("Input date:");
    datePicker = new DatePicker();
    hboxDate = new HBox(datePicker);
    btnCreateProfile = new Button("Create Profile");

    this.add(lSelectCousrse, 0, 0);
    GridPane.setHalignment(lSelectCousrse, HPos.RIGHT);
    this.add(cboCourses, 1, 0);
    this.add(lPNumber, 0, 1);
    GridPane.setHalignment(lPNumber, HPos.RIGHT);
    this.add(tfPNumber, 1, 1);
    this.add(lFirstName,0,2);
    GridPane.setHalignment(lFirstName, HPos.RIGHT);
    this.add(tfFirstName,1,2);
    this.add(lSurname,0,3);
    GridPane.setHalignment(lSurname, HPos.RIGHT);
    this.add(tfSurname,1,3);
    this.add(lEmail,0,4);
    GridPane.setHalignment(lEmail, HPos.RIGHT);
    this.add(tfEmail,1,4);
    this.add(lDate,0,5);
    GridPane.setHalignment(lDate, HPos.RIGHT);
    this.add(hboxDate,1,5);
    this.add(btnCreateProfile,1,6);


}

public void populateComboBoxWithCourses(Course[] courses) {
    cboCourses.getItems().addAll(courses);
    cboCourses.getSelectionModel().select(0);
}


public Button getButton(){
    return this.btnCreateProfile;
}

}
```

And here is my controller

```
public class OptionsModuleChooserController implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>  {

private OptionsModuleChooserRootPane view;
private StudentProfile model;

public OptionsModuleChooserController(OptionsModuleChooserRootPane view, StudentProfile model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;       
    this.view.profilePane.populateComboBoxWithCourses(setupAndRetrieveCourses());

}

private Course[] setupAndRetrieveCourses() {
    .......
}


@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    final Object source = event.getSource();

    if (source.equals(this.view.profilePane.getButton())) {
        System.out.println("Button has been pressed!");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you set the action for the button. So I'd try that first.

Comment: @HypnicJerk that is the issue how would i do that?
btnCreateProfile.setOnAction();
what sould i pass in it?

Comment: `Button`s have a `setOnAction` method. You will need to find a way to set your custom handler in that method.

Comment: You could use a lambda and do it like this: button.setOnAction(e -> {// doStuff});

Comment: Also, I did a very quick search here on stackoverflow and quickly found a similar question that has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724002/set-button-on-action-within-method-java

Comment: @Robert yes i can do that but what i am trying to do is handle all the events from inside the controller not from the view itself.

Comment: Adding the listener within the View class would still allow you to "handle" the event in the controller class. You could just make sure to "notify" the controller that the button was clicked by the user. Would that not work? Otherwise I guess that you could fetch the reference from the view and create the setOnAction inside of the controller. Now I'm not going to try and pretend that i'm any good with MVC, but I don't think, please correct me if I'm wrong, that notifying the controller of the fact that a user action has occurred would "break" it?